# How to make an alert call after a countdown? Calls before for some reason?

Tags: javascript, countdown

I am trying to make a countdown with alerts. It should count down from 50 by 5, with 5 seconds in between. There should be an alert that says "Blast off!" at the end. For some reason, the alert is happening before the countdown finishes, even though it isn't even called until after.

I have tried to use functions instead of just variables and commands, but neither method seems to work.

First attempt:

```
     var countsA=5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert("The time is currTime "+countsA);},50000);
     var countsB=countsA+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsB);},45000);
     var countsC=countsB+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsC);},40000);
     var countsD=countsC+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsD);},35000);
     var countsE=countsD+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsE);},30000);
     var countsF=countsE+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsF);},25000);
     var countsG=countsF+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsG);},20000);
     var countsH=countsG+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsH);},15000);
     var countsI=countsH+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsI);},10000);
     var countsJ=countsI+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsJ);},5000);

    alert("Blast off!");
     </script>
```

Second attempt:

```
<script>
     function countdown() {
     var countsA=5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert("The time is currTime "+countsA);},50000);
     var countsB=countsA+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsB);},45000);
     var countsC=countsB+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsC);},40000);
     var countsD=countsC+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsD);},35000);
     var countsE=countsD+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsE);},30000);
     var countsF=countsE+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsF);},25000);
     var countsG=countsF+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsG);},20000);
     var countsH=countsG+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsH);},15000);
     var countsI=countsH+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsI);},10000);
     var countsJ=countsI+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsJ);},5000);
     }
     countdown();

     function blastOff() {
        alert("Blast off!");
    }

     blastOff();
     </script>
```

Third attempt:

```
 <script>
     var countdownDone = false;

     function countdown() {
     var countsA=5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert("The time is currTime "+countsA);},50000);
     var countsB=countsA+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsB);},45000);
     var countsC=countsB+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsC);},40000);
     var countsD=countsC+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsD);},35000);
     var countsE=countsD+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsE);},30000);
     var countsF=countsE+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsF);},25000);
     var countsG=countsF+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsG);},20000);
     var countsH=countsG+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsH);},15000);
     var countsI=countsH+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsI);},10000);
     var countsJ=countsI+5;
     setTimeout(function(){alert(countsJ);},5000);
    }
     countdown();
     countdownDone = true;


     function blastOff() {
         if (countdownDone = true) {
        alert("Blast off!");
         } 
     }
    }

    blastOff();

     </script>
```

The result, every time, is that "Blast off!" appears before the countdown finishes. I'm getting no error messages in the console.

Comment: setTimeout schedules an event for later. It doses not wait. The execution continues.

Answer (score 0):

> the alert is happening before the countdown finishes, even though it isn't even called until after.

No, it's called immediately. This is the entire purpose of `setTimeout`, to *enqueue* something to happen in the future, and then allow the flow of code to proceed.

If you want the final alert to happen after the others, you need to wrap it in a `setTimeout` just like all the previous alerts, and use a suitable delay.

Answer (score 0):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) dosen't wait. The code execution continues.

I suggest that you use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead, that repeatedly calls a function with (almost) the specified interval, and [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) to stop.

```js
var value = 50;

function handleCountdown(){
 value = value - 5;
 if (value <= 0) {
   alert("Blast off!")
   clearInterval(timer); // Stop the timer
 } else {
   alert(value);
 }
}
// using setInterval instead, that will call the function repeatedly 
var timer = setInterval( handleCountdown, 5000);
```

By the way, using alerts like this is annoying. Do you know about [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)?